# Can I add DropDownList to multiple Table Cells dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

can I add my drop down list twice in different cells? Now it works only for the last cell, so I have one drop down list in las cell. Must I create each time new drop down list or how can I make it?

Thanks in advance

```
    Dim ddltest As New DropDownList
    ddltest.ID = "ddltest"
    ddltest.Width = Unit.Pixel(270)
    ddltest.Enabled = False

    ddltest.Items.Add(New ListItem("text1", "value1"))
    ddltest.Items.Add(New ListItem("text2", "value2"))

    ddltest.SelectedItem.Text = ddltest.Items.FindByValue("value2").Text
    row01.Cells.Add(New TableCell)
    row01.Cells(1).Width = Unit.Pixel(300)
    row01.Cells(1).Controls.Add(ddltest)

    ddltest.SelectedItem.Text = ddltest.Items.FindByValue("value1").Text
    row01.Cells.Add(New TableCell)
    row01.Cells(2).Width = Unit.Pixel(300)
    row01.Cells(2).Controls.Add(ddltest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create you DDL in a function and then add it with different IDs to your cells

```
Private Function DDLCreate(ByVal Id As String) As DropDownList
        Dim ddltest As New DropDownList
        ddltest.ID = Id
        ddltest.Width = Unit.Pixel(270)
        ddltest.Enabled = False
        ddltest.Items.Add(New ListItem("text1", "value1"))
        ddltest.Items.Add(New ListItem("text2", "value2"))
        Return ddltest
End Function
```

and then you can use it as often as you want like

```
row01.Cells(2).Controls.Add(DDLCreate("DDL1"))
row01.Cells(3).Controls.Add(DDLCreate("DDL2"))
```

Cheers Alex